# Codeigniter nginx 404

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

I'm using Ubuntu on webmin nginx.
I am not sure how many times this question has been answered before, but every answer that I look at gives a different approach to solving this problem of which none of them worked. My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` looks like this...

Codeigniter nginx giving continuous 404 error.
What can I do?

My config file:

```
server {

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 00.000.00.00:80;
    root /home/example/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_error_log;
    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/example/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/example/public_html;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/14449619992080.sock/socket;
    }

    listen 00.00.00.00:443 default ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/example/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/example/ssl.key;
}
```

Comment: What do your NGINX logs say ?